# Display & edit tabular data in the terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal, csv, software-rec, spreadsheet

I'm looking for an app to display & edit CSV files as a tabular data in cells, similar to GUI spreadsheets like LibreOffice Calc.
I just need simple viewing, cell editing & easy navigation between cells, w/o complex vim-like shortcuts.

Any suggestions?.

Thanks

Comment: It's been a while since I've needed it, but I do recall a `vim` plugin for CSV files.  Its "complex" shortcuts included Tab and Shift-tab to jump  the cursor to a field to the left or right, as I recall.

Comment: [sc-im](https://github.com/andmarti1424/sc-im) is the usual recommendation; it uses Vim keys, though.

Answer (score 2):

The best tool is for me VisiData
https://www.visidata.org/

Comment: Can this tool be used with [`miller`](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller)?

Comment: Yes @Seamus you can use it